# LDAP invalid credentials - Active Directory Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: active-directory, ldap, windows-server-2012-r2

I have not worked with Active Directory before and I need to make a connection between Unity standalone implementation in C# and Active Directory installed on a Windows Server 2012 R2 via LDAP. Every time I connect, I get the same error:

> LdapException: (49) Invalid Credentials
>   LdapException: Server Message: 8009030C: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903C5, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 2030, v2580

And I am sure that my username and password are correct.

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://"+ serverName+":"+port,userName,password);

    DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(entry);

    ds.Filter = "XX";

    SearchResult result = ds.FindOne();
    ResultPropertyCollection rpc = result.Properties;
    foreach (string property in rpc.PropertyNames)
    {
        foreach (object value in rpc[property])
            console.text+="Property = " + property + "Value = " + value;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Debug.Log(ex);
}
```

I already tried with LdapAdmin (open-source LDAP directory management tool) but I received the same error even with ldp command line in windows PowerShell. Any help will be appreciated.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tgt5V.png)

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: What is the format of the username in `userName`? Is it `domain\username` or `username@domain.com`? (please edit your question rather than adding an answer)

Comment: I tried both but with the same error, can you check the screenshot that I recently added ? Thank you for your time.

Comment: See the answer below. There must be a typo in your username. It's not lying to you :)

Answer (score 2):

It's obscure, but the reason you got denied is in the error message. The real error is the value of the `data` field. In this case, the error is `0x2030`.

Convert the value to decimal to get `8240`.

Then do a lookup of the error. The [FormatMessage API will give you that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/retrieving-the-last-error-code), or on the command line, you would do:

```
net helpmsg 8240
```

And you would get

```
There is no such object on the server.
```

That means the username you are using does not exists, has a typo, etc.